# How to consecutively add values from one array to another and store the value in a new array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures

I have 2 arrays:

`const initialAmount = [50]`

`const transactionAmounts = [ -10, 10, 10, -1, -5, -10, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1, -1, -2, -5, -10 ]`

How do i return an array that adds each value from `transactionAmounts` to the `initialAmount`? (excluding the first, which should be the initial value)

For example, it should return:

`const valueAfterEachTransaction = [50, 40, 50, 60, 59, 54, 44, 49, 54, 59, 69, 79, 89, 90, 89, 87, 82, 72]`

Comment: `const valueAfterEachTransaction = [...initialAmount]
transactionAmounts.forEach((amount,index)=>valueAfterEachTransaction.push(amount+valueAfterEachTransaction[index]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over the sum and get all elememts of both arrays for mapping the acutal sum.

```js
const
    initial = [50],
    transactions = [-10, 10, 10, -1, -5, -10, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1, -1, -2, -5, -10],
    result = [...initial, ...transactions].map((s => v => s += v)(0));

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const initialAmount = [50]

const transactionAmounts = [ -10, 10, 10, -1, -5, -10, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1, -1, -2, -5, -10 ]

const newArray = [initialAmount[0]]
let value = initialAmount[0]
let i = 0 

do {
    value = value + transactionAmounts[i]
  newArray[i+1] = value
  i++;
}
while (i < transactionAmounts.length);
 console.log(newArray)
```

```
const initialAmount = [50]

const transactionAmounts = [ -10, 10, 10, -1, -5, -10, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1, -1, -2, -5, -10 ]

const newArray = [initialAmount[0]]
let value = initialAmount[0]
let i = 0 

do {
    value = value + transactionAmounts[i]
  newArray[i+1] = value
  i++;
}
while (i < transactionAmounts.length);
 console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but this seems to be a straightforward `map`, after you handle the missing initial value.

```js
const combine = ([x], ys) => [0, ...ys] .map (y => x + y)

const initialAmount = [50]
const transactionAmounts = [-10, 10, 10, -1, -5, -10, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1, -1, -2, -5, -10] 

console .log (combine (initialAmount, transactionAmounts))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I'm curious of what your underlying need is.  This seems an odd requirement.  Why is the initial value passed in an array?  Why is there an implied `0` to add to the first one.  Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?